Does buddhist Tripitaka or Sutta literature mention Vishnu or Shiva?
I have heard Buddhist literature Mentions Maha Brahma, a diety attributed with creation but he is still held as a conditioned being.
Does any literature of the buddhist canon (Any tripitaka or sutta) mention vishnu or shiva as deities? If so, what position are they accorded? Are they held to be conditioned beings similar to Brahma or something else?

If we are a Buddhist, we place our trust in the early Buddhist scriptures.
The well known Vedic gods mentioned in the early Buddhist scriptures appear to be primarily Indra (Sakka), Brahma and Pajāpati.
There is a backdating 'Hinduizer' Woke Australian monk named Sujato (who has a chatsite called Sutta Central) who makes tenuous claims about Vishnu & Shiva but the evidence for these tenuous claims appears spurious &/or trifling. Sujato has said:

In the time of the Buddha, and indeed even to this day, the ancient
pre-Buddhist Vedas formed the basis for the spiritual life of the
brahmins and those who followed them. Rituals such as the agnihotra,
the daily pouring of ghee onto the fire as an offering to the fire-god
Agni—originated long before the Aryan people even came to India, and
continue to be performed today.
Nevertheless, many of the old gods featured in the Vedas had vanished
by the time of the Buddha, and many of the famed deities of later
Hinduism had not yet appeared. Those who do appear take on a markedly
different aspect; prominent gods such as Vishnu (Pali: Veṇhu) or Shiva
(Pali: Siva) appear in minor roles, and a warrior like Sakka (AKA
Indra) appears as an apostle of peace. There were no temples, no
images, and no cult of devotion (bhakti). There is no mention of a
system of avatars, nor of familiar concepts from modern Hindu-inspired
spirituality such as śakti, kuṇḍalinī, chakras, or yoga exercises.
Sujato

Sujato's claims above about Vishnu appear to be based on two trivial occurrences (in SN 2.12 and DN 20) of a god named Veṇhu. Similarly, it appears the name 'Siva' for a god is found only once (in SN 2.21). There appear nothing in these three suttas providing the characteristics of these gods which are later found in Hinduism regarding Vishnu & Shiva.

No, none of the Buddhist texts that I have come across, be it Theravada or Mahayana mentioned Vishnu or Shiva. These appeared to be Hindu deities post-dating the historical Buddha.
